# ARM - Load and Store assembly instructions

Tags: c, assembly, arm

I am trying to `load` and `store` data from two different `arm` registers.

```
int testing[64*1024]  __attribute__ ((aligned (8192)));
__asm__("MOV r0, %0" :: "r" (testing) : "r0");
__asm__("STR R5,[R0];");
```

In my initial attempt I tried to store some data pointed to by the register `r0` to register `r5`. There are absolutely *no* compilation problems but the data in the register `cannot be accessed.`

It is the same case for `Load` as well.

```
LDR R1,[R0]



(gdb) info registers
r0             0xb6000  745472
r1             0x1      1
r2             0x0      0
r3             0xb6000  745472
r4             0x8961   35169
r5             0x0      0
r6             0x0      0
r7             0xbeba9664       3199899236
r8             0x0      0
r9             0xefb9   61369
r10            0xf02d   61485
r11            0x0      0
r12            0x0      0
sp             0xbeba9664       0xbeba9664
lr             0x89cb   35275
pc             0xeace   0xeace <test48+14>
cpsr           0x60000030       1610612784
(gdb) bt
#0  0x0000eace in test48 ()
#1  0x000089ca in main ()
(gdb) x/x $r5
0x0:    Cannot access memory at address 0x0
(gdb) x/x $r0
0xb6000 <testing>: 0x00000000
```

Essentially I am trying to achieve some memory inline addressing using ldr and str.

I took  help of [this](http://www.davespace.co.uk/arm/introduction-to-arm/addressing.html) guide while I was building my example

Any idea where I am going wrong

Comment: I recommend using a single inline assembly block, and informing the compiler of all registers you modify (clobbered registers).

Comment: I just tried doing that. No changes. I still cannot access the registers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your comment and your code do not match:

> In my initial attempt I tried to store some data pointed to by the register r0 to register r5 [...]
>   `__asm__("STR R5,[R0];");`

The instruction you wrote stores the value of `R5` into the memory location that `R0` points to. The register `R5` does not point to any memory location - its value is `0x00` in your example.

The `__asm__` statements do not declare the `R5` register used in any way, so the compiler is free to put any temporary value or variable in it. This also explains:

```
(gdb) x/x $r5
0x0:    Cannot access memory at address 0x0
```

Your gdb command tries to access the memory location that `R5` points to - but it does not point at any.

Comment: But I am using `AT&T` syntax, that is, CMD DEST,SRC

Comment: For the STR instruction the syntax is STR SRC,[DEST], as explained in the guide you referenced in your question. Sorry.

Comment: at&t has to do with x86 only, completely irrelevant to arm.

Comment: arm syntax is described in the ARM Architectural Reference Manuals, free downloads from infocenter.arm.com.  the store instruction is the wierd one that doesnt follow a dest=src format of the others, it uses the ldr type syntax as Joe pointed out str src,[dest]  (ldr src,[dest])

Comment: if you want to do arm assembly you really should have one of the arm architectural reference manuals I recommend the oldest which might be associated with armv5 or armv6

Comment: I was mistaken there. I should have taken note the order correctly.